# Why name of thread change after join all jobs in coroutine scope?

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

I have this piece of codes that make me confuse. why if I uses CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch in runBlocking and check it with println(). Every time I test it my

```
println("01 Runblocking Scope Before join() => THis is ${Thread.currentThread().name} and ID is ${Thread.currentThread().id}")
```

will be  different from

```
println("02 Runblocking Scope Before join() => THis is ${Thread.currentThread().name} and ID is ${Thread.currentThread().id}")
```

This is my code.

But if I change from CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch{} to this.launch{} both println() in the orevious line will be same. I thinks that because refer to the same scope(runBlocking{}) but why if I use CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch{} those println() not print the same data.

```
runBlocking {
    println("Outside Scope => THis is ${Thread.currentThread().name} and ID is ${Thread.currentThread().id}")
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
    //this.launch {
    println("Runblocking Scope => THis is ${Thread.currentThread().name} and ID is ${Thread.currentThread().id}")
        val jobs = mutableListOf<Job>()
        for( i in IntRange(0, 10)) {
            jobs.add(CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                printData(i)
            })
        }
        println("01 Runblocking Scope Before join() => THis is ${Thread.currentThread().name} and ID is ${Thread.currentThread().id}")

        jobs.joinAll()

        println("02 Runblocking Scope Before join() => THis is ${Thread.currentThread().name} and ID is ${Thread.currentThread().id}")
        println("Exit Runblocking Scope")
    }.join()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`jobs.joinAll()` suspends the execution until all jobs are finished. This does not mean the current Thread is put on wait.

The state of the coroutine is saved and the current Thread is returned into the Thread pool.

Once all jobs are finished the coroutine continues execution using any available Thread from the Thread pool.

Thats why you see different ids. Nevertheless the behaviour can be different depending many factors. For example running your code on my machine always prints the same ids.

Comment: Thanks sir, you make me understand what I confuse. :)